# how to extract a string using two forward slashes

Tags: c, strstr

I have a string which is always has two forward slashes as `/709/nviTemp1`
I would like to extract the `/709/` from that string and return it in char*, how would I use strstr for that purpose?

I also might have many forward slashes in the path like `/709/nvitemp1/d/s/`

so I only need to get the first token `/709/`

Comment: Do you have to use `strstr` or can you also use other methods? If you _have_ to use `strstr`, is this a homework question?

Comment: not its not a homework question. Yes I can use other methods

Comment: does the 1st "/" always at first position? If yes you just have to "cut" the string after the 2nd one.

Comment: Take a look at [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) and [strrchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strrchr/).

Comment: @hexasoft yes its always at the first position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `strtok` for this. `strtok` splits up a string into different tokens, based on a separator. Like this:

```
char str[100] = "/709/nviTemp1";
char delimiter[2] = "/";
char *result;
char *finalresult;

result = strtok(str, delimiter); // splits by first occurence of '/', e.g "709"
strcat(finalresult,"/");
strcat(finalresult, result);
strcat(finalresult,"/");
printf("%s",finalresult);
```

Please take care of the fact that strtok modifies your original string that you pass to it.

Comment: I want to cut the /709/ not getting the between forward slashes

Comment: do another `strtok`, which will return everything after the second '/' then.

Comment: you didn't get me, I want to extract the /709/ from the string

Comment: Further to your last sentence, it's often a good idea to work with a copy of the string, as returned by `strdup`, which guarantees that the string you modify will exist in memory that is writeable. Declaring the string as char *str="/709/nviTemp1" will crash unless you work with a duplicate. Also, you should only perform 1 strtok, not 3!

Comment: If you know what the delimiter is, then just grab the "709" using `strtok` and then add back the '/' with appends.

Comment: @enhzflep further strtoks after the first are used to get the second and third token. You need these.

Comment: @Magisch - No, no, no, _no_. Perform strtok once, not three times. Try running your code in a machine, not just in your head.

Comment: @enhzflep in documentation it says the second and third call is supposed to return the second and third token. thats why you call it with `NULL` as first parameter. See here on how to use `strtok` : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm

Comment: I dont care what the documentation says - I've read it for over 20 years. Run your code and watch it fail. Again and I wont say it again - perform strtok once. You'll also have to use strcat or something similar to add the required slashes to the start and end of the string. You approach is fine. The implementation is sorely lacking.

Comment: what if there are more slashes in the path, I only need to get the first /709/ in the string.

Comment: @enhzflep and Magisch: I just ran the program (replacing the erroneous quotes in `'/'` with `"/"`) and with `printf("%s\n",result);` after each `strtok` and the output is `709`,`nviTemp1`,`(null)`. I emphasize that I made _no other_ edits to the program posted here.

Comment: I only need to get the first part which has two forwards slashes /709/, there might be more forward slashes in the string to be tokenize, so I only need to get the first one which is /709/ including the forward slashes

Comment: Edited my answer. Apparently it skips the first mention of "/" since there is nothing in front of it. But otherwise works fine. If you wanted the thing after the "/709/" though, you would need 2x strtok

Comment: @Magisch - bingo! Now you've got it.

Comment: @Magisch what If I want to get the last name, and keep it in memory should I strdup each time I call strtok ?

Comment: You should definately make a copy of every string you tokenize with strtok. If by "last name" you mean the part after "/709/" then just call strtok again with NULL as input and the same delimiter.

Comment: Reason for making a copy first is because strtok modifies the string you pass to it.

Comment: token = strtok(str, "/");

 char *re;
 /* walk through other tokens */
 while( token != NULL ) 
 {
  printf( " %s\n", token );
  strcpy(re, token);
  token = strtok(NULL, str);
 }

Comment: @Magisch this fails, while trying to copy the token into a string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92732/discussion-between-magisch-and-andre).

Answer (score 3):

You may try something like this:

```
char str[100] = "/709/nviTemp1";
char resu[100];
char *tmp;

tmp = strchr(str+1, '/');
strncpy(resu, str, (size_t)(tmp - str) + 1);
resu[(size_t)(tmp - str) + 1] = '\0';
```

The `strchr` search the 1st '/', but starting at `str+1` skips the real first one. Then compute "size" beetween start and found '/' and use `strncpy` to copy stuff, and add a trailing '\0'.

Answer (score 1):

To perform the task you've asked about, the following code will suffice. If you need a more general solution, the answer will obviously differ.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *str = "/709/nviTemp1";
    char *delims = "/";
    char *strCopy;

    char *tmpResult;

    strCopy = strdup(str);
    tmpResult = strtok(strCopy, delims);

    // +1 for the first slash, +1 for the second slash, + another for the terminating NULL
    char *finalResult = (char*)calloc(strlen(tmpResult) + 3, 1);

    strcat(finalResult, "/");
    strcat(finalResult, tmpResult);
    strcat(finalResult, "/");

    free(strCopy);

    printf("%s",finalResult);
}
```

**Output:**

> /709/

Answer (score 1):

Use strchr to find first slash. Advance pointer and find the second slash. Advance the pointer and set to `'\0'`.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (int argc , char *argv[]) {
    char *tok;
    char text[] = "/709/nvitemp1/d/s/";

    if ( ( tok = strchr ( text, '/')) != NULL) {//find first /
        tok++;
        if ( ( tok = strchr ( tok, '/')) != NULL) {//find second /
            tok++;
            *tok = '\0';
            printf ( "%s\n", text);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```